# Use AJAX with .htaccess redirected subdomain

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, redirect

i am doing subdomain redirection with;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^.*$ file.php?id=%1 [L]
```

This turns **someid.domain.com** to **www.domain.com/file.php?id=someid**

Everything is ok for now but i am having problem to use AJAX on the page which is posting variables to a file with

```
$.post('post.php', {ID: ID},
```

As you know AJAX wont let to use like **www.domain.com/post.php** but when i write **post.php** bec. of redirection it searches for **someid.domain.com/post.php**

This is what i want;

1- Redirect **someid.domain.com** to **www.domain.com/file.php?id=someid**

2- Redirect **someid.domain.com/post.php** to **www.domain.com/post.php**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `RewriteRule` line to:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ file.php?id=%1 [L]
```

This way, only requests for `/` get rewritten to the `file.php` script, and not *everything*.

Comment: thx for your answer, i did what you've said when i enter someid.domain.com it redirects to www.domain.com/file.php?id=someid it should stay on someid.domain.com

Comment: @new_coder there's nothing in any of those rules that is causing a redirect.

Comment: yeap you are right other line on htaccess conflict with yours when i delete other one it works like a charm.. you are the man you save my hours.. thanks